# How to unit test a custom JsonConverter

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, json.net, nunit

I have a json payload that I want to deserialize in a non-trivial way.

```
{
   "destinationId": 123
}
```

The target class is

```
public class SomeObject
{
    public Destination Destination { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public Destination(int destinationId)
    {
        Id = destinationId;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

To be able to do so, I've created a `JsonConverter` that takes care of it.

Here is the ReadJson method:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    if (CanConvert(objectType))
    {
        var value = reader.Value;

        if (value is long v)
        {
            // TODO: this might overflow
            return new Destination((int)v);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

I have then decorated the Destination class with a `[JsonConverter]` attribute accepting a `typeof(DestinationConverter)`.

This works correctly when I use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeObject>(myString)` (see unit test below) but I'm having issues creating a successful unit test for the `JsonConverter` specifically (see second test below).

```
[Test, AutoData]
public void SomeObject_is_correctly_deserialized(SomeObject testObject)
{
    var json = $@"{{""destinationId"":{testObject.Destination.Id}}}";

    Console.WriteLine($"json: {json}");

    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeObject>(json);

    Assert.That(obj.Destination.Id, Is.EqualTo(testObject.Destination.Id));
}

[Test, AutoData]
public void ReadJson_can_deserialize_an_integer_as_Destination(DestinationConverter sut, int testValue)
{
    JsonReader reader = new JTokenReader(JToken.Parse($"{testValue}"));

    var obj = sut.ReadJson(reader, typeof(Destination), null, JsonSerializer.CreateDefault());

    var result = obj as Destination;

    Assert.That(result, Is.Not.Null);
    Assert.That(result, Is.InstanceOf<Destination>());
    Assert.That(result.Id, Is.EqualTo(testValue));
}
```

I've been googling for a way to properly unit-test a converted but I only find examples of people using the whole `DeserializeObject` instead of just testing the converter.

PS: I pasted all the necessary code in a .NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oUXi6k

Comment: Why do you put `CanConvert(objectType)` in `ReadJson()`?  `ReadJson()` should only get called if it is already known that the converter applies.

Comment: In a previous version, I had issues of the method being called on the second property of the SomeObject class (that class is redacted). Anyway, removing it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Looks like you'll need to provide an implementation of JsonReader.

Comment: `ReadJson()` is an implementation details of deserialization, do you really need to unit test that method? It will be called anyway during deserialization.

Comment: the answer from @dbc clearly showed that I needed it. Besides, unit testing a component is about testing the implementation details of the components using it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your basic problem is that, when you create a `JsonReader`, it is initially positioned *before* the first token.  This is alluded to in the [documentation for `JsonToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonToken.htm):

> **JsonToken Enumeration**
>
> Specifies the type of JSON token.
>
> Members
>
> - `None`:    `0`   This is returned by the JsonReader if a read method has not been called.

Thus, to properly unit-test your converter, you need to advance the reader to the first token of the c# object you are trying to read, e.g. like so:

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json));
while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)
    if (!reader.Read())
        break;

var obj = sut.ReadJson(reader, typeof(Destination), null, JsonSerializer.CreateDefault());
```

Sample fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IEhVv9).

Having done that, I would suggest you rewrite your converter as follows:

```
public class DestinationConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(System.Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Destination);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, object existingValue, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var id = serializer.Deserialize<int?>(reader);
        if (id == null)
            return null;
        return new Destination(id.Value);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter writer, object value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // WriteJson() is never called with a null value, instead Json.NET writes null automatically.
        writer.WriteValue(((Destination)value).Id);
    }
}
```

By calling `serializer.Deserialize<int?>(reader)` inside `ReadJson()`, you guarantee that:

- `null` values are handled during reading.
- An exception will get thrown in case of not-well-formed JSON (e.g. a truncated file).
- An exception will get thrown in case of invalid JSON (e.g. an object where an integer was expected, or an integer overflow).
- The reader will be correctly positioned at the end of the token being read.  (In cases where the token is a primitive the reader does not need to be advanced, but for more complex tokens, it does.)

Sample fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SFT44r).

You might also want to enhance your unit tests to check that:

1. The reader is correctly positioned after `ReadJson()`, e.g. by asserting  the the [`TokenType`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_TokenType.htm) and [`Depth`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_Depth.htm) are correct, or even counting the number of tokens remaining in the JSON stream and asserting it is as expected.

   A common mistake when writing a converter is to leave the reader mis-positioned after conversion.  When this is done, the object *itself* is read successfully but all *subsequent* objects become corrupt.  Unit-testing `ReadJson()` directly will not catch this unless you assert that the reader is correctly positioned afterwards.
2. An exception is thrown for a not-well-formed JSON stream, e.g. one that is truncated.
3. An exception is thrown for an unexpected JSON token, e.g. when an array is encountered where a primitive is expected.

Comment: Thank you sir! Your answer is what makes this site such an amazing resource for the community.

I'll implement what you suggest as soon as I get to sit at my desk.