# Utf8JsonReader.ToString gives: Cannot get the value of a token type 'None'

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, system.text.json

Please note, this is for System.Text.Json and not Json.Net, so [How to unit test a custom JsonConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53176481/how-to-unit-test-a-custom-jsonconverter) isn't a duplicate.

I like to unit test my custom JsonConverter:

```cs
using System.Text.Json;

public class DateTimeShortConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime>
{
    public override DateTime Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        // support yyyy-MM-dd but also with times
        return DateTime.Parse(reader.GetString());
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    }
```

I need a `Utf8JsonReader` and I need to feed that one with a `string`.

I tried this:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("2019-01-02");
var reader = new Utf8JsonReader(bytes.AsSpan());
```

Which seems to work, but gives a crash in the converter when doing `reader.GetString()`:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Cannot get the value of a token type 'None' as a string.
> at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.GetString()

The `reader.GetString()` should be correct, [see Microsoft's example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/system-text-json-support), so I think I feed the `Utf8JsonReader` wrong.

The `reader.Position` is readonly, so that isn't also an option. How could I feed the Utf8JsonReader correctly with a string?

Full test:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
Using Xunit;

[Fact]
public void ReadDateTimeTests()
{
    // Arrange
    var input = "2019-01-02";

    var dateTimeShortConverter = new DateTimeShortConverter();
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
    var reader = new Utf8JsonReader(bytes.AsSpan());

    Type typeToConvert = typeof(DateTime);
    JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions();

    var expected = new DateTime(2019, 01, 02);

    // Act
    var result = dateTimeShortConverter.Read(ref reader, typeToConvert, options);

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(expected, result);
}
```

update: this also doesn't answer my question: [Exception when testing custom JsonConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59028159/exception-when-testing-custom-jsonconverter). I tried also (from that answer) without luck:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
var reader = new Utf8JsonReader(bytes.AsSpan(), false, new JsonReaderState(new JsonReaderOptions()));
```

## Update

`"2019-01-02"` isn't correct JSON in C#, but `"\"2019-01-02\""` is and it still gives the same error.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding this, but your input isn't json ?

Comment: Yes indeed, tried also `"\"2019-01-02\"";`, but that only fails also

Comment: `"\"2019-01-02\""` is not json. Json must be something like `{ "propName": "2019-01-02" }`

Comment: `"2019-01-02"` is valid JSON :) (see https://jsonlint.com/). I needed a `reader.Read();` also, see my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem,

First `"2019-01-02"` is valid JSON, but not `2019-01-02`, so I needed an escape there.

After that, I need one read to read the quote of the string: `reader.Read();`

So this works:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
Using Xunit;

[Fact]
public void ReadDateTimeTests2()
{
    // Arrange
    var input = "\"2019-01-02\"";

    var dateTimeShortConverter = new DateTimeShortConverter();
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
    var reader = new Utf8JsonReader(bytes.AsSpan());
    reader.Read(); // Read the quote

    Type typeToConvert = typeof(DateTime);
    JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions();

    var expected = new DateTime(2019, 01, 02);

    // Act
    var result = dateTimeShortConverter.Read(ref reader, typeToConvert, options);

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(expected, result);
}
```

Comment: How would you go about catching an exception in this test?

Comment: @User9193 see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017295/assert-an-exception-using-xunit